# Vue.js: Pull in data from DOM - Specifically form action attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible, with Vue to create some kind of binding such that the data item in the Vue instance is initialised from the DOM?

Specifically, in my case, I would like my Vue instance to receive the `action` attribute of a form element.

For example, my HTML would look like this (Path generated using server-side code):

```
<form action="path/to/script.php" id="my-form">

</form>
```

And my Vue element would look like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: 'my-form',
    data: {
        action: '' // I want this item to receive 'path/to/script.php' on load
    },
    compiled: function() {
        console.log(this.action); // Should output 'path/to/script.php'
    }
});
```

I've tried doing this, to no avail. The action in the DOM is just removed to match the `action` data item:

```
 <form action="path/to/script.php" v-bind:action="action">

 </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: You only want to get the form action?

```
yourClickFunction: function(e) {
    var formAction = e.target.action;
    console.log(formAction);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is a little unusual, in that the viewmodel usually doesn't pull data from the view, it feeds data to it, so you need a [custom directive](https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html).

The one I wrote below takes the name of an attribute and the name of a data member and makes the assignment.

```js
Vue.directive('initialize', {
  params: ['item','attr'],
  bind: function() {
    this.vm[this.params.item] = this.el.getAttribute(this.params.attr);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#my-form',
  data: {
    action: '' // I want this item to receive 'path/to/script.php' on load
  },
  compiled: function() {
    console.log('Action:', this.action); // Should output 'path/to/script.php'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form" action="path/to/script.php" v-initialize attr="action" item="action">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Coming from a typical jQuery background, I would typically output the `action` attribute of a `form` using server side code and then access it using jQuery. The same could apply when displaying say an "edit" form where I would set the values of the inputs with existing data. In Vue, what would be the usual way to create bindings, while preserving existing values? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Initializations are typically done in the viewmodel code and reflected into the view, so your `action` data item would get the initial value and the HTML would have the `v-bind:action` you tried. Jonathan's answer is also good; using `props` to feed downstream components is a common pattern.

Comment: So would that mean outputting existing values directly into the Javascript, or perhaps by means of AJAX? Thanks for the feedback on my answer though, I'm the author of that answer and the author of the question ;)

Comment: Yes, either/or. Props on your `props` solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get something kind of working using [`props`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props). The `action` attribute isn't exactly bound into the `data`, but it's accessible from within the Vue instance in the same way i.e. `this.action`.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="path/to/script.php" id="my-form">

</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#my-form',
    props: {
        'action'
    },
    compile: function() {
        console.log(this.action); // Outputs 'path/to/file.php'
    }
});
```

Comment: You probably want props to be an array, rather than an object.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't think it mattered too much. I just pasted in some stripped down code that I have in there (Validation/type checking etc): `props: {action: {type: String}}`

Comment: Something I just thought to check: when you designate `action` to be `props`, the attribute is removed from the form tag, so the form's action won't be set any more. You can re-set it in your `compiled` section with `this.$el.action = this.action`

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. Thanks for the tip ;)